# a tag css putting the text in middle y axis

Tags: css, html, tags

I used a tag and wrote my content set a background color, height and width.

I used text-align: center; to align the text in the center for x axis.

How can I align it in middle for y axis?

Comment: Google "Vertical align".

Answer (score 4):

Using flexbox you can specify `align-items: center; justify-content: center;` to center the text in an element.

```css
p {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  }
```

```html
<p>a tag</p>
```